# How to extend JQuery UI plugin

Tags: jquery, user-interface, dialog, extend

The existing dialog plugin doesn't have an option to close dialog on clicking modal overlay, how to add an option to provide the functionality?

Answer (score 1):

```
(function($){
   var _init = $.ui.dialog.prototype._init;
   $.ui.dialog.prototype._init = function(){
        var self = this;
        _init.apply(this,arguments);
        $('.ui-widget-overlay').live('click', function(){
            if (self.options['overlay_close']){
                self.destroy();
            }
        });
    }
})($);
```

Comment: :) incredible! You asked a Q just to answer it?! Well, hope will be useful for someone!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that. SO is a perfectly acceptable place to store knowledge so that you can go back and look at it later. People do it all the time here! See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question

Comment: @lbstr Sure, but I was on the trigger for new questions and than I've seen an answer in after 5 sec! Realizing that the Answerer was actually the O.Poster  - it made my day! +1 :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan hah ya same here! We're all furiously reading the question trying to get an answer in there fast and then you look and see the self-answer. They should really highlight it differently or something.

Comment: There is a checkbox "answer your own question - Q&A style" on the submit question form, so obviously this is advocated by SO.

Answer (score 0):

It would be even better if the self-provided answer worked.

I get no response when clicking outside the dialog. Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/styson/menjK/) for testing.

Maybe I am doing something wrong, but it doesn't seem to do its desired function.

@JamesLin provided the key insight. I needed to add the new option in my initialization:

```
$("#myDialog").dialog({
    overlay_close:true,
    modal: true
});
```

The jsFiddle is also updated.

Comment: should be working now, you were missing this option "overlay_close:true" when initialize your dialog and I have also changed the bind to "live"